# Angular ui-route: $stateparams is empty when using $state.go('url', {params: 1})

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to send paras to my route using the $state.go function.
Here's my code:

```
var promise = $state.go('.list', {listing: [1,2,3], marker: false});
```

The route works, but $stateParams and $state.params are still empty...
Here's the plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/3bpcnR?p=preview

How can I get the params sent via the "go" function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it might be wise if you post your **state definition** here as well using `$stateProvider` because there is a big chance that that's where the problem is coming from.

Comment: I agree with your comment

Comment: Ok, you are right. I've found out the solution. I was missing the /:listing/:marker in my state definition.

Comment: You should at least provide sample code with your solution, so this thread is not useless.